# Контент сайта меньше размера экрана

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На скрине видно, что контент сайта явно меньше текущего размера экрана. Я не уделял внимание этому т.к. почему-то с **header**'ом всё нормально показуется, а вот с **main** всё сужается и становится кривым. Абсолютно не имею понятия в чем причина. Пробовал комментить кучу разных блоков кода чтобы понять, что приводит к этому - безрезультатно. Даже не знаю какой код прикрепить т.к. в **css** общие стили (**wrapper**, **body** и т.д.) комментил причина не в них, скорее проблема фундаментальнее.

Comment: Проблема точно не в вашем меню? И как я выяснил, лучше писать `min-height: 100vh` для `body`, вместо какого либо `height`

Answer (score 0):

Не видно всю разметку html и css - сложно понять в чем проблема.
Но судя по скрину следует сделать:

```
.body: { width: 100vw; box-sizing: border-box; } 
.wrapper: { width: 100vw; }
.main: { width: 100vw; }
```

и добавить  css, сбрасывающий свойства по умолчанию.

Comment: Это не помогло. Но проблему я решил, друг подсказал. Оказалось header слишком большой, на скрине оно и видно, как он вылазиет. Его либо уменьшить как то, либо сделать на проблемном разрешении бургер меню.